# Blazor equivalent of ng-template

Tags: blazor

An Angular component can have an arbitrary number of child templates that it references. For instance, I could make a Foo component that specifies some body content inline, along with templates for additional content:

```
<Foo>
    This is my body
    <ng-template #header>
        This is my header
    <ng-template>
    <ng-template #footer>
        This is my footer
    <ng-template>
<Foo>
```

The Foo component can reference these templates as "ChildContent" and use them in its markup:

```
<div>
    <h1>
         <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="header"></ng-template>
    </h1>
    <div>
       <p>Hi! I'm a Foo. My body content:</p>
       <p><ng-content></ng-content></p>
    </div>
    <h3>
         <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="footer"></ng-template>
    </h3>
</div>
```

So my example usage of Foo (first code sample above) would be rendered into the DOM as:

```
    <div>
        <h1>
             This is my header
        </h1>
        <div>
           <p>Hi! I'm a Foo. My body content:</p>
           <p>This is my body</p>
        </div>
        <h3>
             This is my footer
        </h3>
    </div>
```

What is an equivalent in Blazor? In other words, I'd like to be able to define a component Foo such that it can be passed render fragments inline via in its child content markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blazor uses a RenderFragment class and property to produce template regions.

In the example below, we have templates for the Header, Body, and Footer as you described in your Angular example.

```
<div>
        <h1>
             @HeaderTemplate
        </h1>
        <div>
             <p>Hi! I'm a Foo. My body content:</p>
             <p>@ChildContent</p>
        </div>
        <h3>
             @FooterTemplate
        </h3>
    </div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment HeaderTemplate { get; set; } 

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } 

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment FooterTemplate { get; set; } 

}
```

Usage:

```
    <Foo>
        <HeaderTemplate>
             This is my header
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ChildContent>
           <p>This is my body</p>
        </ChildContent>
        <FooterTemplate>
             This is my footer
        </FooterTemplate>
    </Foo>
```

Note: The order of the templates in the usage example do not matter.

**Invalid** Usage:

```
    <Foo>
        <!-- this will fail, because Blazor cannot determine where the <p> content belongs. -->
        <p>This is my body</p>
        <HeaderTemplate>
             This is my header
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
             This is my footer
        </FooterTemplate>
    </Foo>
```

Comment: I mentioned render fragments in my question: I want to "pass render fragments inline via in the child content markup".  Your example shows how render fragments can be rendered in a component (which I already know), but not how those render fragments can be populated by child markup at the component's point of use (my first example).

Comment: I find the Angular templates a bit confusing. I'll try to see if I can help find an answer. Blazor components can have ChildContent which is a RenderFragment and named by convention, or named templates as the example shows. You cannot mix the two without explicitly placing the ChildConent element in the body of the component. However, these items do not require a particular order, they will render where the @templateName is used.